# Unit testing to check that the accept was called when using RxBindings

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java2, rx-binding

```
AS 4.0.2
RxBindings 4.0.0
```

I have written a unit test for testing if the PublishRelay accept has been called that uses jakeWartons rxBindings

This is the snippet of code I am testing

```
private val checkStoresRelay: Relay<Unit> = PublishRelay.create<Unit>()

private fun onCheckStockTapped(view: View) {
    view.textViewCheckStock
        .clicks()
        .debounce(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribeBy(
            onNext = checkStoresRelay::accept,
            onError = { Timber.e(it, it.localizedMessage) }
        )
}
```

In the test class I am doing the following. The `textViewCheckStock.performClick()` will trigger and I check that the checkStoresRelay.accept(Unit) had been called.

But I am not sure about the `availableDeliveryOptionsModel.checkStoresRelay.accept(Unit)` As I don't think I should be calling this in the test. However, the test will fail if I remove this. Just wondering what would be the best way to test this?

```
@Test
fun `should check stores when checkStock is tapped`() {
    // Arrange
    val viewHolder = createViewHolder()
    availableDeliveryOptionsModel.bind(viewHolder)
    val actual = availableDeliveryOptionsModel.checkStoresRelay.test()

    // Act
    availableDeliveryOptionsModel.checkStoresRelay.accept(Unit)
    viewHolder.itemView.textViewCheckStock.performClick()

    // Assert
    actual.assertValue(Unit)
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't call `relay.accept()` directly within your test. `accept` should be called on your behalf in `subscribeBy()`. The problem is based on `.debounce()` operator.

Debounce waits for a given amount of time and if there isn't subsequent emit (view click), it emits item downstream (into `.subscribeBy()`). This creates some delay and results in a test failure, because `actual.assertValue(Unit)` is called **before** click (emit) is delivered.

You can solve this issue with [RxSchedulerRule](https://github.com/Plastix/RxSchedulerRule). Execution of debounce operator is done immediately on the current thread, so you'll basically handle item delivery to relay and run assertions after.

I have simplified your example a little bit, but I hope the main point remains:

```kotlin
class SO64328289 {
    val checkStoresRelay: Relay<Unit> = PublishRelay.create()

    fun onCheckStockTapped(view: View) {
        view.clicks()
            .debounce(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeBy(
                onNext = checkStoresRelay::accept,
                onError = { Log.e("SO64328289", it.localizedMessage) }
            )
    }
}

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [28])
class SO64328289Test {

    @get:Rule val schedulerRule = RxSchedulerRule()

    @Test
    fun `when button clicked then relay emits value`() {
        val tested = SO64328289()
        val view = View(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

        tested.onCheckStockTapped(view)
        val relayTestSubscription = tested.checkStoresRelay.test()

        view.performClick()

        relayTestSubscription.assertValue(Unit)
    }
}
```

I have used Robolectric, but it should also work with other testing frameworks. These are dependencies I have used in my test project if you want to try it for yourself:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.1.1'
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.20"

testImplementation 'com.github.Plastix.RxSchedulerRule:rx2:1.0.2' // requires jitpack.io maven
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0'
```